# What is max_pfn_mapped used?

Tags: kernel

In the function setup_arch in arch/x86/kernel/setup.c, it has the printouts:

```
printk(KERN_DEBUG "initial memory mapped: [mem 0x00000000-%#010lx]\n",
                    (max_pfn_mapped<<PAGE_SHIFT) - 1);
```

What is the different between max_pfn_mapped and max_low_pfn_mapped?

When I boot in x86 machine, I see that the max_pfn_mapped has value 20000000 (512MB)

```
initial memory mapped : 0 - 20000000
```

Where is in the kernel source code set max_pfn_mapped value?

Comment: Do you mean linux kernel? Or some of the BSDs?

Comment: http://lxr.free-electrons.com/ident?v=2.6.36;i=max_low_pfn_mapped